# Getting xcode error code when I try to build and run C++ program

Tags: c++, xcode

https://imgur.com/a/L2xro

my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    // Declare named constants for tax and tip rates
    const double TIP_RATE = 0.20; // 20%
    const double TAX_RATE = 0.0675; // 6.75%

    // Declare variables for inputs and results
    double mealCharge;
    double tax, tip, totalBill; // Results

    // Initialize all input variables
    cout << "What is the cost of the meal?: $ ";
    cin >> mealCharge;

    tip = mealCharge * TIP_RATE;
    tax = mealCharge * TAX_RATE;
    totalBill = mealCharge + tip + tax;

    cout << "Your meal cost is: $ " << mealCharge << endl;
    cout << "Your tax amount is: $ " << tax << endl;
    cout << "The tip you should pay is: $ " << tip << endl;
    cout << "Your total cost for the meal is: $ " << totalBill << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The error message:

duplicate symbol _main in:

```
/Users/*******/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/C++_Error_Resolution-eiuslwrjycbgywdfhqxyxsmklwep/Build/Intermediates/C++ Error Resolution.build/Debug/C++ Error Resolution.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main.o

/Users/********/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/C++_Error_Resolution-eiuslwrjycbgywdfhqxyxsmklwep/Build/Intermediates/C++ Error Resolution.build/Debug/C++ Error Resolution.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fixingErrors.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Everytime I try to write and build a program on xcode this happens, I have  written numerous javascript files in xcode with no problems at all. I know windows pc's are superior for coding but in my opinion xcode should be able to process a pretty basic C++ program.

Is there a way to fix this or would I have to take my laptop to apple and see what they can do about it?

Comment: Edit your question to include the error messages as text, not as a link.

Comment: "_use -v to see invocation_" Have you done this?

Comment: It looks like you're linking together `main.o` and `fixingErrors.o`.  This should not be necessary for such a simple one-function program.

Comment: Remove `fixingErrors.cpp` from the target.

Answer (score 1):

As @aschepler says, you are linking together `main.o` and `fixingErrors.o`, and *each* object defines `main`.

Linking together two object files (unnecessary for this trivial example, but useful for more complicated ones) is done all the time, but you *can't* link together two object files that define the same function.

Comment: @M.Gaddaffi You should stop linking the second object in. Precisely how to do that in xcode I don't know. Presumably it's in the "project configuration" somewhere.